# How can I fix the issue between li buttons?

Tags: jquery, html

good afternoon I am something new with the front-end the doubt is how to solve the error that when I click on the languages ​​button and another button of the nav to change it I seem that I am still in the button and I realize in the hover That Is there still the color when the li is open, in jquery I have something like what I can solve that?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown keep-open">
    <a id="dLabel" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)" data-animation="scale-up" aria-expanded="false" role="button">
      <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span> English</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></span> French</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cn"></span> Chinese</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"></span> German</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-nl"></span> Dutch</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Notifications" aria-expanded="false" data-animation="scale-up" role="button">
      <i class="icon wb-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="badge badge-danger up">5</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-media" role="menu">
      <li class="dropdown-menu-header" role="presentation">
        <h5>NOTIFICATIONS</h5>
        <span class="label label-round label-danger">New 5</span>
      </li>

      <li class="list-group scrollable is-enabled scrollable-vertical" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
        <div data-role="container" class="scrollable-container" style="height: 270px; width: 373px;">
          <div data-role="content" class="scrollable-content" style="width: 358px;">
            <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left padding-right-10">
                  <i class="icon wb-order bg-red-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="media-heading">A new order has been placed</h6>
                  <time class="media-meta" datetime="2016-06-12T20:50:48+08:00">5 hours ago</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left padding-right-10">
                  <i class="icon wb-user bg-green-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="media-heading">Completed the task</h6>
                  <time class="media-meta" datetime="2016-06-11T18:29:20+08:00">2 days ago</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left padding-right-10">
                  <i class="icon wb-settings bg-red-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="media-heading">Settings updated</h6>
                  <time class="media-meta" datetime="2016-06-11T14:05:00+08:00">2 days ago</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left padding-right-10">
                  <i class="icon wb-calendar bg-blue-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="media-heading">Event started</h6>
                  <time class="media-meta" datetime="2016-06-10T13:50:18+08:00">3 days ago</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left padding-right-10">
                  <i class="icon wb-chat bg-orange-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="media-heading">Message received</h6>
                  <time class="media-meta" datetime="2016-06-10T12:34:48+08:00">3 days ago</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-bar scrollable-bar-vertical scrollable-bar-hide" draggable="false"><div class="scrollable-bar-handle" style="height: 205.043px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></div></div></li>
      <li class="dropdown-menu-footer" role="presentation">
        <a class="dropdown-menu-footer-btn" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button">
          <i class="icon wb-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
          All notifications
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="navbar-avatar dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false" data-animation="scale-up" role="button">
      <span class="avatar avatar-online">
        <img src="../../global/portraits/5.jpg" alt="...">
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-payment" aria-hidden="true"></i> Billing</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i> Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-power" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$('.keep-open').on({
  "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { 
    $(this).attr('closable', false); 
  },
  "click": function() { },
  "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { 
    return $(this).attr('closable') == 'true'; 
  }
});

$('.keep-open #dLabel').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('closable', true );
  }
});
```

First click:
[image: [first click]]

Second click:
[image: second click]

Comment: *«it seems to stop»* and *«it's not working»* is not a clear description of the issue. Please, be more "descriptive" about the behavior wanted and the one that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to do with your jquery, it's a css problem it's not handle properly you need to check your css codes look for :active & :focus , I guess it should apply in `<li class="dropdown keep-open">`, since you not shared your css it's hard to find the exact problem.